# Does element of order zero and element of order infinity in a group mean the same?

Tags: group-theory, cyclic-groups

In my recently appeared test I got a question mentioned below:

> 1) In an additive group $G$ of integers, the order of inverse element $a^{-1}$, for all $a \in G$ is
>
> (a)  $0$
>
> (b)  $1$
>
> (c)  $\infty$
>
> (d)  none of these.

I got it right by choosing option (c). But I was in confusion as I thought element of order zero and infinity are the same. does element of order zero and element of order infinity in a group mean the same? Is option (a) also correct?

Answer (score 2):

No, the order is infinity, not zero. I have a few more details that might help:

Note: I will use the notation $na$ to mean $\underbrace{a+a+\cdots+a}_{n\  \mathrm{times}}$.

Let $G$ be an additive group, $a \in G$. The order of $a$, $|a|$, is defined to be the smallest $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $na = 0$. If such an $n$ does not exist, $|a|$ is infinite.

However, if we have a ring $R$, the characteristic of $R$ is the smallest $n\in\mathbb{N}$ such that for all $r\in R$, $nr = 0$. It's essentially the least common multiple of the orders of each of the elements in $R$. However, if such an $n$ doesn't exist, we don't say the characteristic is infinite. Instead, we say $Char(R) = 0$.

This is probably where your zero/infinity confusion comes from.

Comment: Can you give me an example of a group where element is of order zero.

Comment: Note that if we define "smallest" in the sense of the division order and include $0$ in $\Bbb n$, then the case of a ring of characteristic zero is already included in the definition, and doesn't require a separate convention.

Comment: No such thing exists. $0$ has order one, because "one copy of it" gives you $0$. Anything other element $a$ in the group is non-$0$, so you need at least two copies of $a$ to get $0$.
In summary: $|0|=1$, and $|a| > 1$ where $a \neq 0$.

Comment: In my book it says" if there exists no $n$ such that $a^n=0$ then a is of infinite order or zero order".is my book wrong?

Comment: I would say "non-standard" rather than wrong.